# Rename `shell_exec` from PHP

Tags: php

I am using `disable_functions` of PHP to block functions like `exec, shell_exec` inside `php.ini`.  However this affects my entire virtual hosts. I cannot choose some specific virtual host to allow `shell_exec`, for example. I searched a lot and it looks like an impossible task without additional extensions (like `suhosin`).

So I am wondering: I will block `shell_exec` in my `php.ini` BUT I will try to "rename" `shell_exec` inside `php.ini` to another function like `my_secret_shell_exec` so only I know the function name and I will assign this function name to do exactly as the `shell_exec`.

Is this even possible? I mean, renaming an internal function of PHP to a name that only I know so I can safely use it whenever I need?

Comment: Even if you did rename it, this would thwart your efforts. https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.get-defined-functions.php `get_defined_functions ([ bool $exclude_disabled = FALSE ] )`

Comment: If using apache, enable mod_php and specify custom INI file with `PHPINIDir `

Comment: @daan the problem of using custom php.ini is that my customer will be able to ovewrite my php.ini file placed inside their root hosting account.